# XAMPP MySQL Terminating worker thread 1

Tags: mysql, xampp

I used to work with XAMPP to build PHP applications. Once I tried Zend engine and uninstalled it. After that, MySQL in XAMPP is not working. It is giving "Terminating worker thread 1" error. 
  When I check ports, 
 MySQL has status Service: MySQL_ZendServer51.

Pleas help me how to reassign it back to XAMPP? I have reinstalled XAMPP several times. But no use.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should delete the old mysql service.

Assuming you have Vista or Windows 7:

1. Go to Start and type `cmd.exe` in the search field and hit Ctrl+Alt+Enter. This will start the command line as `Administrator`.
2. Now you can type `sc.exe delete MySQL_ZendServer51` to remove the service.
3. Now you can start your XAMPP Control Panel and uncheck the "svc" checkbox next to MySQL (if it's not already)
4. Next check it on again (this will install the proper `mysql` service)

And make sure you don't have to server running (which could be possible, that Zend installed it's own mysql but for some reason didn't removed it?)

Comment: Thank you. Actually I went to Services by clicking SCM on XAMPP. then I stopped MySQL_ZendServer51. Now XAMPP MySQL is running good.

Answer (score -1):

I just went here: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe
And opened the document and MySQL Started without problem.